# I can't get my Ms Access Form to save information back to the table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I'm very new to MS Access and this problem has me stumped. I think I'm missing obvious, I just can't pinpoint what it is. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

At the moment I have one table: `tblAll` with the following fields:

- `ID` (PK)
- `PackageNo`
- `PackageDescription`
- `Activity`
- `ProductivityRateLow`
- `ProductivityRateHigh`
- `Unit`
- `TimePeriod`
- `Notes`
- `Source`
- `LeadTimeLow`
- `LeadTimeHigh`

My form contains combo boxes:

- `cboPackageNumber`
- `cboActivity`

And text boxes:

- `txtRateHigh`
- `txtRateLow`
- `txtUnit`
- `txtTimePeriod`
- `txtSource`
- `txtNotes`
- `txtMax`
- `txtMin`

I have added three buttons:

- `cmdSave`
- `cmdAdd`
- `cmdClose`

The user first selects the Package Number from `cboPackageNumber`, then selects the Activity from `cboActivity`, from a list of activities associated with that package. Once the Activity is selected the rest of the text boxes are populated with the data for that activity.

This all works great to look up records from the table. However, I would like users to be able to save changes to the records in the form back to `tblAll`. I also want to be able to add new records. At the moment if any information is changed in the text box fields on the form it is not saved back to the table.

The code for the `cmdSave` I copied from another source, which seemed to be what I was trying to achieve with the save function.

Sorry to dump all my code here again, I'm hoping this makes it easier to understand where I am and where I'm going wrong.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Private Saved As Boolean
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboActivity_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtRateHigh = [cboActivity].Column(5)
    Me.txtRateLow = [cboActivity].Column(4)
    Me.txtUnit = [cboActivity].Column(6)
    Me.txtTimePeriod = [cboActivity].Column(7)
    Me.txtSource = [cboActivity].Column(9)
    Me.txtNotes = [cboActivity].Column(8)
    Me.txtMax = [cboActivity].Column(11)
    Me.txtMin = [cboActivity].Column(10)
End Sub

Private Sub cboPackageNumber_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "SELECT o.ID, o.PackageNo, o.PackageDescription, o.Activity, o.ProductivityRateLow, o.ProductivityRateHigh, o.Unit, o.TimePeriod, o.Notes, o.Source, o.LeadTimeLow,  o.LeadTimeHigh " & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM tblALL AS o" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE o.PackageNo = '" & cboPackageNumber.Value & "'" & vbCrLf & _
    "ORDER BY o.PackageNo;"
    Debug.Print strSql
    cboActivity.RowSource = strSql

    If cboPackageNumber > 0 Then
        cboActivity.Visible = True
        Me.cboActivity.Requery
    Else
        cboActivity.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
   Saved = True
   DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdSaveRecord)
   Me.cmdSave.Enabled = False
   Saved = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim Response As Integer
    If Saved = False Then
        Response = MsgBox("Do you want to save the changes on this record?", vbYesNo, "Save Changes?")
        If Response = vbNo Then
           Me.Undo
        End If
        Me.cmdSave.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    On Error GoTo cmdAdd_Click_Err

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If

cmdAdd_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdAdd_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdAdd_Click_Exit
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.cmdSave.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You are making this far more difficult than need be. Use UNBOUND combobox to find existing record. Don't use values from combobox to set values in textboxes. Bind textboxes to fields. This will show existing data and user can edit and changes will pass directly to table. User can move to NewRecord row manually or with your custom button.

Comment: A record entry/edit is committed to table when: 1) close table/query/bound form; 2) move to another record; 3) run code to save. http://allenbrowne.com/bug-01.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question (especially the formatting). Use bold font in only rare cases (to mark sth as important) or it decreases readability. Use backticks for form controls and show table structure [formated as table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), one row for each column and add datatype after fieldname.

Comment: @June7 Sorry I'm still very confused. I have now changed it so the second combo box works on a query after the first combo box is selected. The text boxes are now bound to the correct fields but don't display any information relating to the record selected in cboActivity. I feel incredibly stupid not being able to understand what should be simple.

Comment: As I said, use an UNBOUND control (combobox or textbox) to enter criteria to search for record. This will require some code (macro or VBA). Or use the intrinsic filter/search tools on ribbon or right click menu. Have you studied an introductory tutorial book? It will explain how to do this. If your comboboxes are BOUND, all you are doing is changing data in record.

Comment: More than one way to accomplish. For filtering, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: @June7 First of thanks for you help and your patience, its much appreciated. I got it to work as you explained. I had to delete the combo boxes and recreate them through the wizard, then everything worked as expected. Combo box allows scrolling through the records and the text boxes display the information for the record correctly, also the save button now functions as expected. However, I cannot get the first combo box to filter duplicate records as I had before, I know this is because of the primary key which needs to be included.

Comment: What I should have explained is the two combo boxes cascading is crucial too how the form needs to work for finding and adding records. The first combo box shows the package number, of which there are about 30. This list of package numbers is fixed and will never change. Every record (Activity) is assigned to one of these package numbers. I need the first combo box to show only unique package numbers, once the package number is selected then second combo box filters the activities with that package number. Can this be done with one form and still have the ability to save and edit records?

Comment: Why include the ID PK if you want to find all records associated with PackageNo? Maybe you should normalize data structure. Have a table Packages where each package is a unique record. Have a related dependent table PackageActivities for associated activities. Use form/subform for data entry/edit.

Comment: Your question is two-fold: How to code Cascading comboboxes and how to use combobox values to filter form. Yes, this can be done with your one table and one form bound to that table to allow find and edit. The ID PK is irrelevant for the Packages combobox, include ID in Activities combobox RowSource. Filter Activities combobox on PackageNo, use ID from Activities selection to search/filter form. The 'search' comboboxes must be UNBOUND.